# Synonymes de « se donner les moyens » ?

Tags: expressions, synonymes

Connaissez vous des synonymes de cette expression ?

> Se donner les moyens de faire quelque chose

Comment: Pas très précis comme question. Quel est le but ?

Answer (score 3):

Ce ne sont pas des synonymes au sens strict, mais des transpositions possibles :

> - Se procurer les outils pour travailler à
> - Trouver des solutions pratiques au problème
> - S'offrir les moyens de réussir

Answer (score 3):

> Se donner à fond
>
> Tout faire pour
>
> Se donner corps et âme
>
> Se faire violence

Renvoient un peu à la même idée

Answer (score 3):

Peut être l'un des suivants:

> Mobiliser les ressources nécessaires
>
> Faire l'investissement requis
>
> Mettre en place les conditions (préalables) pour réussir

Answer (score 2):

*Se donner les moyens , pour ...* (faire quelque chose, obtenir quelque chose):

- faire tout ce qui peut être nécessaire ou utile pour y arriver;
- mobiliser suffisamment de ressources pour y arriver.

Exemples:

- Se donner les moyens pour réussir un examen = prendre des cours, réviser beaucoup, ...
- Se donner les moyens pour perdre du poids = faire un régime sévère, suivre **toutes** les recommandations du médecin, ...